# Flask Get all products from table and iterate over them

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a website that uses Flask as the backend, and I am trying to add all products from a table into the webpage.

I've never used SQLAlchemy or anything like it, so I'm not sure how exactly to get all the products from a database, and then categorize them as I need for the website.

Here is the code I'm using in views.py

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    product = [
        {
            'product_name': 'T-Shirts',
            'product_price': '18.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 2',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 3',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 4',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 5',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 6',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 7',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 8',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 9',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 10',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 11',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 12',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 13',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 14',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
        {
            'product_name': 'TShirts 15',
            'product_price': '25.00',
            'product_img': '',
            'product_description': 'A t-shirt, again.'
        },
    ]
    return render_template("products.html",
                           title="Products",
                           products = product)
```

Here is the code in my template (This works perfectly):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/Straight_Up_Performance_Logo.png') }}">

                <div class="hide-for-small panel">
                    <h3>Straight Up Racing</h3>
                    <h5 class="subheader">Straight Up Racing believes that the best way to get in touch with our customers is for
                    them to call us. Give us a call at (406) 239-4975 to order yours today!
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-8 columns">
               <div class="row container1">
                   {% for product in products %}
                       <div class="large-4 small-4 columns">
                           <ul class="pricing-table">
                               {% if product.product_name %}<li class="title">{{ product.product_name }}</li>{% endif %}
                               {% if product.product_price %}<li class="price">${{ product.product_price }} + S&H</li>{% endif %}
                               {% if product.product_img %}<li class="bullet-item">{{ product.product_img }}</li>{% endif %}
                               {% if product.product_description %}<li class="description">{{ product.product_description }}</li>{% endif %}
                           </ul>
                       </div>
                   {% endfor %}
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Here is the code that created the Product table:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    product_price = db.Column(db.Float, index=True)
    product_img = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)
    product_description = db.Column(db.String(1000), index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product %r>' % (self.product_name)
```

My question isn't why it's not currently pulling data from the database, I know it's using what I manually define. I don't know how to go about pulling it from the database using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to show all products, you need SQLAlchemy's [all](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all) method.

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    products = Product.query.all()
    return render_template("products.html",
                           title="Products",
                           products=products)
```

If you wish to filter by some field, you will want to use SQLAlchemy's [filter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) or [filter_by](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).

```
products = Product.query.filter(Product.product_name == 'TShirts 11').all()

# or

products = Product.query.filter_by(product_name='TShirts 11').all()
```

Comment: Wow. That's extremely easy. I feel kind of stupid now. I have another (potentially stupid) question. When I set the price of a product to 18.00, it changes it to 18.0 instead. Is there anywhere to set the precision to two decimal points instead of one? I have tried the following code:

`product_price = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2), index=True)`

It doesn't work. I also have used precision=3

Comment: You really should ask that as a separate question, but here's a hint, it's not an issue with how you store it (`18.0 == 18.00`), it's an issue with how you display it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have. That's what I was thinking, but was kind of confused as to why it was displaying that way. I'll have to do a bit more research.